# How to install tar.gz2 file on a debian distribution?

Tags: installation, debian

I'm quite lost in linux environement. I usually install application using `apt-get install` and the name of the package.

[Here](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)'s a quite cool text editor named 'Sublime text 2' and I would like to install it in a Debian distribution.
When I download files I get a .tar.bz2 file. 
I unpack the file with a `bz2` command and a `tar` command. And then I'm blocked. Somebody says to me I have to Make a `./configure` and after that a `make` to compile the sources but the `./configure` command doesn't work.

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: What do you mean by "[the] command doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install it directly from the tar.bz2, unzip it, and run `python PackageSetup.py` inside the directory.

Comment: Ok, I choose this one because it answer exactly the question

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to add the PPA for this to your sources list. This will keep it automatically updated for you too.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
```

This will make it so that you can now run `sudo apt-get install sublime-text-2` and it will work.

Comment: @bAN that is the PPA address

Comment: yes I see but where did YOU get it?

Comment: @bAN I found it on launchpad, the website that hosts all the repositories